# Track audio recording in android

Tags: android

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
    // 5 Minutes = 300000 Milliseconds

    recorder.setMaxDuration(300000); 
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
    recorder.setOutputFile(path); 
    recorder.prepare(); 
    recorder.start();
```

This is my code for recording an audio..

I need to track the time at each seconds to show the recorded time like `00:05` . I Have given a time limit of 5minutes.

Comment: @Jim Blackler I need to track the audio recored in each seconds and display it in the screen

Comment: Hi Jennifer, here's a nice tutorial to do something like that  http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html  You can start the clock when you start your recording.

Comment: i think OP means a sort of bar that shows the time elapsed since the start of recording.

Comment: Thanks Jim Blackler I got it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks  **Jim Blackler** I got it :).

I tried [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

```
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    ...

    OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mStartTime == 0L) {
    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
    }
    }
    };


private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
final long start = mStartTime;
long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds = seconds % 60;

if (seconds < 10) {
mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
} else {
mTimeLabel.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds); 
}

mHandler.postAtTime(this,
start + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 1) * 1000));
}
};
```